# Rails Datetime split setter method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a datetime column in a model and I want to display the form for this as separate text_fields for the time instead of the datetime_select helper drop down menus.

I know I will somehow have to validate and recreate the date to go back to the DB, but I am not sure how.

Should I use virtual attributes getter and setter methods? EG...

```
def virtual_minute=(minute)
  ...
end

def virtual_hour=(hour)
  ...
end
```

Or maybe in a callback?

A bit stucko!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to write these yourself if you're using an ActiveRecord model. Multi-parameter attributes can be submitted via forms in pieces. As an example look at how the  datetime_select method you're not too fond of works:

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper/datetime_select

Internally the various parameters get submitted with order and type information so that they can be properly encoded. You can build off of this functionality by simply naming your fields the same way. It is not too hard to copy a helper method you like and put the adjusted version in your ApplicationHelper module.

The values here show up as parameters named something along the lines of:

```
model_type[attribute(1i)]
model_type[attribute(2i)]
model_type[attribute(3i)]
```

These are combined in the correct order, converted as required, and submitted to a constructor for that attributes particular type, such as DateTime.

This avoids having to create your own wrapper methods.

In any case, the easy way to create attributes is to use the attr_accessor method, such as:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :some_date
end
```

That will create the appropriate accessor and mutator methods.

You can use a before_validation trigger to recombine the values in a single pass, or write a wrapper around the date retrieval method to reconsruct it as required.

Answer (score 1):

Virtual attributes are good IMO since they store the user data in an instance variable.
Then in a `before_save` you construct a Time object assign it to the real variable.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to split the time from the date (i think this is your question) when I took a look at the [source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/date_helper.rb) and found the `:ignore_date` option:

> **time_select** will also generate 3 input hidden tags, for the actual
>   year, month and day unless the option **:ignore_date** is set to
>   true.
>
> If you set the **:ignore_date** to true, you must have a **date_select** on the same method within the form otherwise an
>   exception will be raised.

In other words, by setting it to true it's possible to split the date and the time.

See [time_select](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper/time_select) and [date_select](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper/date_select)

(it's also possible to use the datetime select with `:discard_day`, `:discard_hour` ...)